# VBA hangs when other application opens a Dialog box

Tags: vba, api, winapi

I use SendMessage API function to click a button in a user form in another application which opens a dialog box. The vba stops at SendMessage and wont execute further until that dialog box is closed.I want the vba to run as it has to fill up a text box in the newly opened dialog box. Any help is appreciated.

```
sub api_click_button()
a = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Exenta Solution")
b = FindWindowEx(a, 0&, "WindowsForms10.MDICLIENT.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", vbNullString)
c = FindWindowEx(b, 0&, "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", "Inventory")
d = FindWindowEx(c, 0&, "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", vbNullString)
Dim xcoord As Long, ycoord As Long, opn_file As Long, winrect As RECT, retval As Long

retval = GetWindowRect(d, winrect)
xcoord = (winrect.Right - winrect.Left) / 2
ycoord = (winrect.Bottom - winrect.Top) / 2
opn = (ycoord * &H10000) + xcoord
retval = SendMessage(d, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, ByVal CLng(MK_LBUTTON), ByVal opn) ===>stops here 
retval = SendMessage(d, WM_LBUTTONUP, ByVal CLng(MK_LBUTTON), ByVal opn)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's entirely normal.  Input events are *posted*, not sent, so you need to use PostMessage() instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm looking into postmessage function, if you could give me an example using my code, It will help me. Thanks again.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Same principles apply to mouse input. If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video in the link helped me get it working
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-2khNFYQl8

I created a vbs script file with sleep function that fills the dialog box and closes it. I executed the script file before sendmessage.

Comment: Hi @Srini, thanks for sharing the solution and you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if it does solve your issue.